# RTP Streaming raw AAC

Tags: audio, core-audio, audio-streaming, rtp

I have raw AAC frames (variable size) and I want to stream them over RTP. I have their ADTS header.

```
header sample : 
0xff 0xf9 0x5c 0x60 0x7 0x40 0x00
```

According to [this](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=ADTS) the format is :
mpeg-2 (strange because I tell encoder to output mpeg-4) /
no crc /
AAC LC /
22050 Hz /
mono channel /
1 AAC frame

I tried to add [this header (part 3)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-avt-rtp-mpeg2aac-02) and this sdp :

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP6 ::1
s=No Name
c=IN IP6 ::1
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 55.7.100
m=audio 6000 RTP/AVP 14
a=rtpmap:14 MPA/22050/1
```

Without any success, ffmpeg keep telling "header missing", any help would be appreciated